# re-map browser-forward and back keys to media next and last track

Tags: keyboard, media-keys, button-remapping

I've tried sharpkeys but it did not detect these keys. [this keyboard](http://eg.pricenacdn.com/files/images/products/original/275/Rapoo-X8210-Wireless-Keyboard-Mouse-Black_1897576_5cf445e2c2370e126ae62b57dbb1454f_t.jpg)

So I found that the code in sharpkeys for these keys are not the same and by using keycodes3 I found that the forward key's code is 167 and the back is 168 but I don't know the scan code for it to remap using sharpkeys.

Any help to get the scan code or to use the registry for that? Thanks in advance.